# Trying to push first app to SAP, getting error "exceeded the total routes". How can I correct this?

Tags: sap-cloud-foundry

I am taking Pivotal's [Cloud Foundry training](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS132x+1T2017/courseware/05655ef9d6cf4b388239a47663b6b4a8/2336c77fbbdc48029ead67ce44bafe20/?child=last). I set up a 30 day trial account at SAP and trying to push my first "hello, world" application, but getting error

> Updating app web-app...
>
> Mapping routes...
>
> You have exceeded the total routes for your organization's quota. FAILED

How do I increase that quota? (This is my first and only push! Not sure why I am exceeding anything!)

I tried

```
> cf org P2000121914trial_trial
Getting info for org P2000121914trial_trial...

name:                 P2000121914trial_trial
domains:              cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com
quota:                SUBSCRIPTION_QUOTA
spaces:               victor
isolation segments:
```

I also tried

```
> cf create-quota small -m 2048M -i 1024M -r 10 -s 10
Creating quota small as vgrazi@gmail.com...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You are not
authorized to perform the requested action
```

My manifest looks like this:

```
---
applications:
- name: web-app
  memory: 32M
  disk_quota: 256M
  random-route: true
  buildpack: "https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack#v1.6.47"
```

Answer (score 5):

Quotas in public CF deployments are typically set by the platform operator and are not adataptable by customers unless you have received [Org Manager Permissions](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html#roles). I'm quite suprised this appears to be provisioned incorrectly at SAP.

In any case, you might try a `cf routes --orglevel` to see all the routes your org is consuming.

It sounds like this won't apply to your case, but a common "beginner" mistake in CF is that deleting an app does not delete any routes associated with it because they might still be in use by other applications. You can delete routes that are not associated with any app using `cf delete-orphaned-routes`.

In summary, this might be something that only their support can fix for you.

Plug: If you want to get up and running quickly, there are also providers that offer CF hosting with free tiers for developers. I'm a co-founder at [Meshcloud](https://www.meshcloud.io/en/home-2/) we also offer a [free 30-day trial](https://panel.meshcloud.io/#/register). I can assure you org & space quotas are set up correctly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, you need to assign some quota to your space.  You do this in the SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit.

1. Select your CF Subaccount -> Quota Plans
2. Create a "New Plan", set some Memory capacity within that.
3. Assign the Plan you created to your Space.